# Recursive CTE is very slow despite minimal records

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, recursive-query, query-performance, db2-400

I'm trying to write a recursive CTE query similar to [this](http://www.mcpressonline.com/sql/techtip-combining-multiple-row-values-into-a-single-row-with-sql-in-db2-for-i.html) and when limiting my CTE records to an extremely small samples size the results are correct.  I'm assuming it remains correct with more records.  However, if I limit the CTE to ~5000 records (using a where clause) I'm getting 11 second execution times overall.  If I increase that to ~24,000 records (using a where clause) that jumps up to 3 minute execution times.

I haven't run the query for longer than that because I don't want to eat up system resources.

I know I can avoid using a CTE all together for this query, but the intention is for this particular query to be apart of a larger query, so it would be more readable if I could use a CTE.  I'm also pretty confident recursive CTE's are capable of handling much larger data sets, so I'm curious if someone notices something I'm missing.

Here is the query (tables and fields name have been changed):

```
WITH TEMP (COL1, COL2, CURR, PREV) AS (
    SELECT  COL1, 
            COL2,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COL1 ORDER BY COL2) AS CURR,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COL1 ORDER BY COL2) -1 AS PREV
    FROM    MYLIB.MYTABLE
    WHERE   COLDATE > 20150101 -- Produces about 5000 records
    -- WHERE COLDATE > 20140101 -- Produces about 24000 records

)
SELECT  COL1, MAX(TRIM(L ',' FROM CAST(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(COL2, ',') AS VARCHAR(256))))
FROM        TEMP
START WITH  CURR = 1
CONNECT BY  COL1 = PRIOR COL1 
AND         PREV = PRIOR CURR
GROUP BY    COL1;
```

Note*: COLDATE is only being used to limit the records in the CTE for testing purposes.

The CTE itself doesn't seem to be the issue, I can do a `SELECT * FROM TEMP;` and it is instantaneous.  I believe I may be using `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH` and/or `CONNECT BY` incorrectly (IE: I can modify the query to be more efficient)

The link I provided goes into more detail, but what I'm trying to achieve is to turn this:
[image: Original Table]
Into this:
[image: Return Result Set] On the fly.

Which is what it is doing at the moment, albeit very slow.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed two things and managed to work out a solution for my use-case.

First: I realized after executing the same exact query twice, all subsequent queries were near instantaneous.  So I suppose it just had to build a query plan and then everything was fine.  If I modified the query just the slightest bit, it would take a while though because it had to re-build the query plan.

Second: I realized I did not need to perform the query on the entire table.  I only had to tailor this for a single value of `COL1`.  Once I converted this into a UDF I was then able to make use of this individually for each record rather than tackle all records at once.